# Does anyone know how i resolve this warning in my reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs

```
 Warning:   Unnecessary escape character:\.  no-useless-escape
```

-
     Below my code, I got one warning in my console. when i use regex validation in my register form.

```
 Here is my code,

 const reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if (!reg.test(this.state.emailId)) {
            emailIdError = "invalid email";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape periods when they're in a capture group. Just `[.-]` is fine.